# How to fix ambiguous type variables without enabling LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes?

Tags: haskell

The following code

```
type Board a = [(Position, Char)]
new :: (Eq a) => [Char] -> Board a
new a = (zip [NW,N,NE,W,M,E,SW,S] a) ++ [(SE,'X')]
```

for a small game I'm making gives the error

```
Could not deduce (Eq a0)
      from the context: Eq a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   new :: forall a. Eq a => [Char] -> Board a
        at Game.hs:34:13-39
      The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    * In the ambiguity check for `new'
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      In the type signature: new :: (Eq a) => [Char] -> Board a
```

I've done some research and I know that the issue is related to type ambiguity etc., but I can't get any fix to work. Some sites suggested adding type annotations but that didn't help.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have `a` at all?  `Board` doesn't use it.  The solution here is to delete it.

Comment: I will repeat myself again, since you haven't seen this yet: Haskell beginners shouldn't write type synonyms. Use `data` or `newtype` as appropriate; don't use `type`. `type` is only really useful in combination with advanced language features like `TypeFamilies`, `ConstraintKinds`, and arguably `RankNTypes`. The definition `type String = [Char]` in the `Prelude` is widely seen as a mistake (for multiple reasons).

Comment: @dfeuer that's _your opinion_, not a universally held one in the Haskell community. Anyway it's rather besides the point here because the question would be exactly the same if the OP had used a `newtype`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I am entitled to my opinions as much as anyone. Yes, it was a bit to the side.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to add an `Eq a` as type constraint: you do not use a function `(==)` or `(/=)` for type `a` (or for any other type). You thus can implement this with:

```
--   ↓ no Eq a
new :: [Char] -> Board a
new a = (zip [NW,N,NE,W,M,E,SW,S] a) ++ [(SE,'X')]
```

nor do you need an `a` in general: your `Board` type uses `a` as a type variable, but that `a` is not used in the type expression.

You thus can rewrite this to:

```
--       ↓ no a
type Board = [(Position, Char)]
```

--    ↓ no Eq a / no a ↓
new :: [Char] -> Board
new a = zip [NW,N,NE,W,M,E,SW,S,SE] (a ++ "X")